# Función Asíncrona no funciona como requiero en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, async

eh tenido el siguiente problema usualmente cuando utilizo Async y Await en Flutter.

Cuando deseo establecer una conexión a mi bd para obtener cualquier información algunas veces las llamadas de la función asíncrona funcionan perfectamente, con esto me refiero a que regresa los datos como se esperaba, pero algunas ocasiones al invocar estas funciones no regresa los datos, obteniendo valores nulos cuando esperaba algún String , List, etc y hasta que termina el código del programa cuando las consultas vuelven a ejecutarse y regresan los valores esperados (ya no son nulos).

A continuación te enseño la manera en la cual usualmente construyo mis funciones Asíncronas y es que realmente se que no tiene nada de complejo crear una función asíncrona en flutter:

```
 pdffile(algo) async {
    File pdfFile = await PdfApi.generateCenteredText('Sample Text', algo);
    PdfApi.openFile(pdfFile);
  }
```

El código anterior es muy sencillo y muestra la manera habitual en la cual creo algunas promesas para obtener ya sea información, imágenes , listas, etc.

pero cuando realizo consultas en la BD en este caso firebase ocurre que no siempre regresa los datos cuando debe, ya que debugueando la app me puedo dar cuenta que la consulta no regresa información , y es hasta que el programa se ejecuta completamente cuando la función vuelve a ejecutar y esta vez regresa la información correcta, pero al ya haberse ejecutado todo el código del programa esa información correcta ya no se utiliza.

Mi consulta en una clase distinta :

```
Future<Uint8List> getcertificate() async {
    Uint8List bodyBytes;
    http
        .get(
            'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/ejemploimagen')
        .then((response) {
      bodyBytes = response.bodyBytes;
      File('my_image.jpg').writeAsBytes(bodyBytes);
    });

    return bodyBytes;
  }
```

en este caso yo solo busco obtener la cadena de bit de una imagen .
pero cuando mando a llamar esta función en mi código principal obtengo null, y es hasta que todo el código restante y los widgets se ejecutan cuando nuevamente la función se ejecuta y obtiene los valores correctos.

```
 prueba() async {
    try {
      Uint8List imagen = await ManagerDB().getcertificate(); //imagen regresa null 
      imagen != null ? pdffile(imagen) : "Enlace no encontrado";
    } catch (e) {
      print("enlace no encontrado");
    }
  }
```

no se si me lógica esta mal en algún momento, pero me a estado causando problemas el no poder obtener la información cuando debe ser, ya que las funciones asíncronas se están realizando hasta el final del programa.
Si puedes ayudarme al darme cuenta que estoy haciendo mal te lo agradecería, Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas `Future` y quieres `esperar` para obtener el resultado para que el método pueda retornarlo, necesitas usar `await`.

En lugar de esto

```dart
Future<Uint8List> getcertificate() async {
    Uint8List bodyBytes;
    http
        .get(
            'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/ejemploimagen')
        .then((response) {
      bodyBytes = response.bodyBytes;
      File('my_image.jpg').writeAsBytes(bodyBytes);
    });

    return bodyBytes;
  }
```

Debería ser así :

```dart
Future<Uint8List> getcertificate() async {
    final response = await http
        .get(
            'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/ejemploimagen');
    final bodyBytes = response.bodyBytes;
    await File('my_image.jpg').writeAsBytes(bodyBytes);
    return bodyBytes;
  }
```

más info [www.youtube.com/diegoveloper](http://www.youtube.com/diegoveloper)

Comment: gracias eso a funcionado, no había podido ver que me hacia falta el await en esa función